# Development use of iOS 4.0 (8A293)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I recently upgraded my new iPod from iPhone OS 3.1.3 to iPhone OS 4.0 (8A293). However wen attached with xcode organizer i get following error.

OS Installed on Panks’s iPod
4.0 (8A293)

Xcode Supported iPhone OS Versions
4.0 (8A274b)
3.2
3.1.3
3.1.2
3.1.1
3.1
3.0.1
3.0

I tried to downgrade IOS to 4.0 (8A274b) however wen installation is complete it says OS expired error msg and just shows connecting itunes icon.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried updating xcode?

Comment: I am using xcode 3.2.3, I looked for if any newer update is available.

I was not able to find any announcement from apple about newer xcode release.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have one of the developer betas of Xcode installed. The 8A274b build was for the beta right before the gold master was released. Just download the latest SDK and install it over your current install.